# How to find another phone is on or off

Tags: android, telephony

**Is it possible to find another phone number is on or off**.

I think it depends on service provider and in India there is no service provider gives information. In Uruguay it is possible!! and if it is possible so how i can check this in India?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for a phone to be on or off?  Does it mean that the phone number is not in service, or are you referring to a cell phone be turned on or off?

Comment: referring to a cell phone be turned on or off? is it possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard for determining if a cell phone is powered on or off.  Most of us can tell if a cell phone is powered off when calling a phone by the fact that it goes to voice mail immediately. Usually there is no ring-back when this occurs but it may differ slightly from carrier to carrier.  The other issue with using this as a determination is that the user can select to avoid the call which if they are fast enough may give similar results to the caller.

You may be able to make a determination on whether a cell phone is on or off using call progress analysis, but for the fore mentioned reasons it will not be 100% accurate.  One way to get call progress analysis is to use [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) with a platform that has good call progress analysis like [Voxeo's Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/). If you look at their [documentation on CCXML](http://docs.voxeo.com/ccxml/1.0-final/) there is a section on outbound dialing that covers call progress analysis. You would look to see if there was no ring-back before the answer to determine if the phone is off.